# Quickly App Web application

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade, webapps

After I submitted my app for the showdown I would like to know whether it would be possible to make a Webapp out of it. Is it possible with a desktop app created with Quickly/Glade/Python or is it easier to do re-implement it? I'm just curious whether I could reuse my code...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This actually is possible but i dont believe the feature is enabled in ubuntu yet, gtk has a backend called broadway which allows you to use any gtk application in a web browser how well this works i do not know but there are videos around demonstrating the technology.

But generally what everyone else has already said write a separate application.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu's WebApps, coming in Ubuntu 12.10, are essentially websites that are integrated into the desktop. Websites are usually written in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP, while applications on Ubuntu typically are written in Python, C, C++, Java, etc. Therefore I'm pretty sure it's impossible to turn your application into a website without rewriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Daniel already explained to you, desktop applications are completely different in the code. In your case, you've used Python to code and Glade to design the window of your application.
Web applications are basically websites that are heavy JavaScript coded.
Python as the programming language can't be used in websites, and your applications GUI is made in Glade, which means it's GTK based XML file. Websites use HTML + CSS to make things visible to you. Lets say their "GUI" is made in the combination of those two, which aren't the same as XML files native desktop applications are using.

You would need to rewrite the code in **JavaScript**, make a webpage and embed it into a WebKit made with **Python and GTK**. That's in the case you want it to look a bit like a native app, or use that new **Ubuntu WebApp** feature that has been released earlier this week.

Comment: I heard that Gtk3 can be uses for creating webapps by integrating with html5

Comment: Do you mean that you create a WebKit in a Gtk3 window and display the application as a html5 webpage inside the WebKit? Then that's what I meant in the post above. That basically means you create a web browser with "lack on features".

Comment: No it is about implementing gtk in html5 , not implementing html5 in gtk(via webkit)